# Converting string To dateTime using the format of the Client Machine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model that is bound to a View

```
public class ReportModel
    {
        [Required]       
        [DateTimeValid]
        public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
        [Required]        
        [DateTimeValid]
        public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the Class for DateTimeValid Which Inherits from ValidationAttribute

```
 public class DateTimeValid:ValidationAttribute
    {
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            DateTime time;           
            var isvalid = DateTime.TryParseExact(Convert.ToString(value), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out time);
            return (isvalid);


        }
    }
```

TryParseExact Always Returns False no matter how i input the date in the browser.

My Aim is to get the date from the view and convert it to a DateTime with the format of the client Machine.

Also Would like to mention that I have used Jquery Datetime Picker for the user to select the dates.

Any help would be highly Appreciated

Also Am I Doing this the Right Way? Am I missing Something?

Comment: In which format you are passing the `datetime` string to the `TryParse` method?

Comment: I have used a DateTime Picker from Jquery and it prints out the the date format based on the machine date Format.. in my case that would be M/dd/yyyy. I also did try changing the format manually with no positive result

Comment: if you pass the date up in ISO 8601 format then you should always know exactly what the date is and can convert it into the correct .net DateTime object correctly every time without any issues. Then if you return the same format to the front end it can do the same. I think this is what you're asking but if I'm on the wrong tangent just ignore me

Comment: This is responsibility of client to provide valid values in format expected by API. Format date in known format on client side - ISO8601 standard is common one `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.ff`

Comment: regarding my earlier comment, see:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp and in .net just DateTime.Now.ToString("o")

Comment: another universal date format is something like "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" but I'd go with the ISO 8601 and never look back personally

Answer (score 4):

The reason this returns false is because the value of the date has already been converted to a DateTime. If you check the value of `value` when stopped at a breakpoint, you will see it is a DateTime object.

After that, `Convert.ToString(value)` will yield a result of something like `"1/1/2010 12:00:00 AM"` whereas the pattern you're matching against will be something like `"M/d/yyyy"`, which will cause TryParseExact to fail.

Those examples are from my en-US machine. Your outputs may look different but the idea is the same.

Comment: hi, but the Input for the tryparse has to be a string. What needs to be done?

Comment: The issue is that it's too late to try to analyze the raw input from the client if your model specifies a DateTime. You can change the model to use a string instead of a DateTime, but that's going to cause more headaches later when you go to consume the value. The other option is to override the model binding behavior for that model type and implementing the parsing logic there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the proper format of your date. Based on your code, you want a ShortDatePattern, which equals to (**forward slash**):

```
01/01/1985
```

And not other formats e.g:

```
01-01-1985
```

If you use the proper format, it will return true:

[image]